# TFS Build 2015 “Access to Path Denied”

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a solution with around 70 projects inside, and occasionally (maybe 1/5 runs) during the 'Get Sources' stage of the TFS build definition, it will stop with the following error:

```
Access to the path 'D:\BuildAgent2018\_work\1\s\Implementation\Release\FileHelpers.dll' is denied.
```

'FileHelpers.dll' is a NuGet package which we pull into multiple different projects in the solution, however, we commit the packages directly to source, we don't use NuGet restore in the build definition, the first step is 'Get Sources' - which is where it sometimes fails.

When the software is built in release mode, it builds itself into the \Implementation\Release folder, but it's definitely worth noting that in the actual source, the \Implementation\Release folder is empty, therefore files such as 'FileHelpers.dll' only get there by the project being built in release mode, meaning that 'FileHelpers.dll' comes from a previous build on the build server.

I've heard that disabling multi-threaded builds could fix the problem, because it's multiple projects copying/deleting the same file at the same time that could be a cause of this issue, however, all the explanations say something along the lines of:

*Make sure to explicitly run MSBuild with:*

```
/p:BuildInParallel=false
```

or

```
/m:1
```

This doesn't seem like this would have an effect though, since the only place I can specify that argument is during the project build step, and the error occurs at the 'Get Sources' step (which is before the build step).

The weird thing is though that when I get this issue, it happens on every single build after that point, and is only fixed by reboot, which makes me think that the multi-threading scenario is less likely.

- We also only ever run 1 build at a time (the agent has a build queue).
- We have 'Clean' enabled for the mapped repository.

Any ideas what could cause this 'Access to the path 'X.dll' is denied.' error?

If you need me to post more detail, or snippets of code please comment and I'd be happy to do so!

EDIT - The file is in use by 'TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe', even when a build is not running

Comment: If you are currently Open the folder 
 `D:\BuildAgent2018\_work\1\s\Implementation\Release` and forget to close it this will occur in some cases. Make sure you or any other user not open this folder in their File explorer

Comment: @Jayendran thanks for the response, but the folder is not open, the file says it's in use by 'TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe', which is not file explorer sadly.

Comment: Did you try to kill the process manually and try again ?

Comment: @Jayendran when I restart the build machine, it works just fine for a while (which is the same as killing it manually), but it comes back after a while.